# Ошибка Sql Server 2008 R2 Standart Edition

Tags: sql

При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения.
Как решить?

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке же все сказано

Comment: а как узнать разрешены ли удаленные соединения?

Comment: надо смотреть настройки sql сервера. Вы бы добавили конкретики в свой вопрос, а то сейчас это будет похоже на *гадание по кофейной гуще*, не забывайте писать ник того кому пишите сообщение в комментариях, в виде `@`НикПользователя, что бы была нотификация

Answer (score 1):

Обычно такое сообщение появлется, когда служба SQL Server не запущена.
Проверьте и запустите вручную.

Comment: переустановил SQL SERVER, всё работает!